# Change all file permissions to 644 and all folder permissions to 755 recursively

Tags: chmod, directory, permissions, recursive

How to change all file permissions to 644 and all folder permissions to 755 recursively using chmod in the following two situation:

- If they had `777` permissions
- Regardless of the permission (with ANY permissions)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`find . -type d -perm 777 -exec chmod 755 {} \;` (for changing the directory permission)

`find . -type f -perm 777 -exec chmod 644 {} \;` (for changing the file permission)

If the files/directories dont have `777` permissions, we easily remove the `-perm 777` part. The advantage of these commands is that they can target regular files or directories and only apply the chmod to the entries matching a specific permission.

`.` is the directory to start searching

`-type d` is to match directories (`-type f` to match regular files)

`-perm 777` to match files with 777 permissions (allowed for read, write and exec for user, group and everyone)

`-exec chmod 755 {} \;` for each matching file execute the command `chmod 755 {}` where {} will be replaced by the path of the file. The `;` indicates the end of the command, parameters after this `;` are treated as `find` parameters. We have to escape it with `\` since `;` is the default shell delimiter, it would mean the end of the `find` command otherwise.

Comment: How does this work? What are the curly brackets and backslash for?

Comment: Why (??)  this is better tham `chmod -R a=r,a+X,u+w /your/path` ?

Answer (score 15):

Regardless of the permissions:

```
chmod -R a=r,a+X,u+w /your/path
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: according to man chmod:
The  letters  rwxXst select file mode bits for the affected users: read (r), write (w), execute (or search for directories) (x), execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (X) ...

Comment: +1, this is way much faster than the accepted answers if you have thousands of files

Comment: Excellent! This inspired a one liner to reset permissions to umask `chmod -R "$(umask -S | sed 's/x/X/g')" /your/path`

Comment: @Jimbali It works as follows: `all=set to readonly,all=add execute if folder,owner=add write` ... And it is INFINITELY better than all the stupid `find` answers. Find has to launch a chmod process for every file/folder. @adaptr 's answer only does a single, efficient chmod process.

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo find /path/to/someDirectory -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 644
```

and

```
sudo find /path/to/someDirectory -type d -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 755
```

Comment: How is this better than the accepted answer?

Comment: @kasperd It's much worse, because it sends all filenames as arguments all at the same time. This can lead to too many arguments on the line. **THE ONLY GOOD ANSWER** in this whole question is by adaptr who does it properly with just `chmod` itself.